# How to get turtle graphics to not show turtle while its being drawn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

How do I get the final drawing to display without having to show the process of drawing? I am using Python 3.4, and this project is to create an archery game. For example, if I use the following code:

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
turtle.circle(10)
```

A circle with a radius of ten is drawn with an arrow, but I just want a circle shape without seeing it being drawn.

Comment: just a note, import turtle, screen = turtle.Screen(), and turtle.circle(10) were meant to be on separate lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to hide the turtle:

```
turtle.hideturtle()
```

And then set the speed to fastest:

```
turtle.speed(0)
```

Comment: With the turtle invisible, you will probably also want to add the command to run it full speed, without the default artificial slowdown.  (I forget the name; it is in the doc.)

Comment: Thank you :) that worked. turtle.speed(0) makes it so no animation happens.